# Gmail Sidebar gadget development, getting started

Tags: api, rest, gmail, google-apps-script

I'm kind of new to dealing with Gmail API and I have a question regarding the development environment.

I want to create a simple application that fetches unread emails from a gmail user, sends it to a processing server of mine (RESTful web service) where I analyze the data and extract some information, then finally use the extracted information to add it to the user's Google calendar.

I was thinking of developing a sidebar gadget but I was curious about which IDE to use. Do I use the Google scripts API? Will it make my gadget portable? Which IDE to use?

I know about the Gmail API that uses oAuth access to IMAP & SMTP but how can I integrate it with the sidebar gadget? Where do I write the code? Which language?

Answer (score 2):

First, you will want to read [Google's Gmail gadget documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gadgets_overview) to learn how to make them.

Basically, you can either use the [Google Gadget Editor (GGE)](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/legacy/gs.html#GGE), which is a very simple IDE that runs in your browser, or you can use whatever editor you prefer for editing JavaScript and XML. You will also need a website where you can post your code. A google gadget is an XML+Javascript file that resides in some webserver and that follows the schema google dictates.

Google Apps Scripts are a different thing. They are scripts that run in a google spreadsheet and can access the user's google services (docs, gmail, and some other ones). But, they are not Gadgets. To write one, create a new spreadsheet then go to Tools->script editor.

IMAP and SMTP are another thing. They are protocols for talking to a mail server. There are imap and smtp libraries available for nearly all programming languages. But, that is not what you want if you want to implement a gadget.

Comment: I have worked on the GGE and as you said it was quite simple. but my issue is that I need to fetch emails then send them to another server. That is why I want to use IMAP for gmail. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to consider is that Apps Script is the only way to get full access to Gmail.  You could easily automate all the processing to send the information to Calendar.

Comment: I need to send the emails to an external server to do some processing. Any idea how I can do that? Thanks.